# Access JSP variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

**How do I pass the JSP variable to javascript function in external file?**

I have the following set up

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/date/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"  src="js/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myScript.js" ></script>
<link href="js/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="js/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/myCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="myDIV">
      <c:set var="myVar" value="${myInVar}" />
      <script>runMyScript();</script>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now inside my javascript, I try to access the jsp variable but neither of the two ways I found online works:

```
var javaScriptVar = '${myVar}';
var javaScriptVar2 = "<%=myVar%>";
```

Instead of the actual value of the jsp variables, I get the strings.

I read in this answer: [Passing variable from JSP to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727137/passing-variable-from-jsp-to-javascript) which suggest to declare the variables before I include the javascript file, but I can't figure out how to do that.

If I put them in the header, they are not resolved because they come from a backend request. 
If I don't include the script in the header and add src attribute to the script section before making the call, the method is never executed.

Totally confused here.

Comment: what do you mean by 'I get the strings.'? What is the actual output you get.

Comment: I mean the string is not evaluted, it's just a string. The value ends up being "<%=myVar%>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JavaScript is inside a `.js` file. The server will (exceptional circumstances aside) treat that as a static file. It will just serve it up to the client without processing.

If you want to run JSP code (such as `<%=myVar%>`) then put it in a JSP file.

Comment: Both the body and header are in JSP files.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. JSP is not evaluated in the external file, so pass them into the function in the external file.